# How do i check if the object proberty (title) has the same value?

Tags: javascript

the taskText has the value of an input, All i want is to check if you user has entred the same value or not

```
  const task = {
id: Date.now(),
title: taskText,
completed: false,
```

};

```
    if(task.title === task.title){
       console.log('true')
       } else {
               console.log('false')
                                   }
```

Comment: with your code, you could skip the `if` and just always log true. But probably that is not what you want, so "user has entered the same value" as what? what do you want to compare it to?

Comment: *"if you user has entred the same value"*: there is no code here that takes the user's input.

Comment: i'm making to do app list, All i want is when a user writes the same task, I don't want it to be printed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please properly format and indent your code so that it's easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what you aim for, but from what I undersant you want to check if `taskText` input have same value as `task.title`. Then you need to define an other value than `taskText` for your title, because what you do is asign `taskText` to `task.title` but you don't compare them doing that.

```js
const task = {
id: Date.now(),
title: "some text",
completed: false,
};

if(task.title === taskText){
console.log('true')
} 
else{
console.log('false')
}
```